# Are there Spanish equivalents to the "DNS", "DNF" and "DSQ" abbreviations for races?

Tags: abreviaturas, deportes, legislación

When watching the Olympic games or similar, international competitions, there are some abbreviations shown in the race registers that state the following:

- **DNS**: The participant did not start the race.
- **DNF**: The participant did not finish the race.
- **DSQ**: The participant was disqualified.

I was wondering, are there Spanish equivalents to these abbreviations when the competition is held in a national scope? If so, do these abbreviations depend on the country, or is there an international agreement between the Spanish-speaking countries? Or do they use the international, English abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las abreviaturas que mencionas son las [oficiales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Terminolog%C3%ADa_del_atletismo#Descalificaciones) de la [International Association of Athletics Federations](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asociaci%C3%B3n_Internacional_de_Federaciones_de_Atletismo) (IAAF).
La [Real Federación Española de Atletismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Federaci%C3%B3n_Espa%C3%B1ola_de_Atletismo) (RFEA), como miembro de la IAAF a través de la [European Athletic Association](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asociaci%C3%B3n_Europea_de_Atletismo) (EAA), hace uso de dicha terminología oficial en todas las competiciones que organiza.

En competiciones a nivel local para *amateurs* o simplemente festivas, puede que se utilicen otras abreviaturas, pero serían abreviaturas *ad hoc* para entenderse entre las 3 o 4 personas que organicen el evento y ya está.
Por ejemplo, en los [resultados de la XXXIII Carrera Popular "Villa de Aranjuez"](https://www.mychip.es/resultado/xxxiii-carrera-popular-villa-de-aranjuez-33/not_finished), en vez de "DNF" ponen simplemente "RETIRADO".